# How to make Ruby endless Range return Infinity

Tags: ruby, range

Ruby introduced [*Endless Range*](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/2.6.html#endless-range-1) in Ver.2.6 and [*Beginless*](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/2.7.html#beginless-range) in Ver.2.7.

I expect the sizes of endless/beginless or beginless Ranges are always infinite (`Float::INFINITY`), considering "*endless*" and *beginless* are (I interpret as) abstract terms.

However, I realise the size of (only) the *endless* Range of String is `nil` (see the last line of the example below), whereas the sizes of `(..nil)`, endless/beginless Numeric Ranges, and even beginless String Ranges are Infinity.

```rb
(..nil).size  # => Float::INFINITY
  (..3).size  # => Float::INFINITY
  (3..).size  # => Float::INFINITY
 (..?a).size  # => Float::INFINITY
 (?a..).size  # => nil(!)
```

In fact, I find that it (= the behaviour for the String class) is the case for an arbitrary user-defined class.

```rb
class MyC
  def succ
  end
end

(..MyC.new).size # => Float::INFINITY
(MyC.new..).size # => nil(!)
```

Why is it so?

How can I make `(MyC.new..).size` return `Float::INFINITY`, in the same way as `(..MyC.new).size` and (..3).size?
I suppose I could redefine `Range#size`, maybe in combinatin with `refine` and `using`, but it seems to me like a dirty hack……

Note all tests above were run with Ruby-3.1.2p20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Range#size`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Range.html#method-i-size) says...

> Returns the count of elements in self if both begin and end values are numeric; otherwise, returns nil

Which means `(?a..).size` is `nil` as expected, but `(..?a).size` should also be `nil` yet it isn't.

Even if one follows [the example from the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Range.html#class-Range-label-Ranges+and+User-Defined+Classes) it is still `nil`.

```
class Xs
  include Comparable
  attr_accessor :length
  def initialize(n)
    @length = n
  end
  def succ
    Xs.new(@length + 1)
  end
  def <=>(other)
    @length <=> other.length
  end
  def to_s
    sprintf "%2d #{inspect}", @length
  end
  def inspect
    'X' * @length
  end
end

p (..Xs.new(5)).size # => Float::INFINITY
p (Xs.new(5)..).size # => nil(!)
```

The `size` documentation and implementation may need to be updated in light of beginless and endless Ranges. This might be a candidate for a bug report.

Comment: I now understand this looks like a bug of Ruby (thanks for your clarification!). I've compiled it into a Ruby bug report [(18983)](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/18983). Related, `(0.5..5.quo(2)) #=> 3` does not easily make sense, either, because "elements" of such a Range cannot be defined. Seemingly, the numbers are `#round`-ed. I've reported it, too [Bug #18984](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/18984).